# How can I move the files on unix with java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, file-copying

I write java in netbeans.I want to move files and create files.When I run the program on netbeans it works. Files creates and moved. But when I run program on the jar it doesnot copy or move. I give permisson jar and files for read , write. But it does not works.And I open jar with root user. how can i fix this?

this is my code to copy

```
package aaa;

import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MoveFolder 
{
    public   int copy(String from,String where  )
    {   
        int onay=0;
        File srcFolder = new File(from);
        File destFolder = new File(where);

        //make sure source exists
        if(!srcFolder.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist."); 
            onay = -1;
          // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Directory does not exist.");

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
                onay = -1;
           //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Was not Copied.");
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
         return onay;
    }

    public   void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
        throws IOException{


        if(src.isDirectory()){

            //if directory not exists, create it
            if(!dest.exists()){
               dest.mkdir();
               System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                              + src + "  to " + dest);
          //          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Directory copied from " + src + "  to " + dest);
            }

            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = src.list();

            for (String file : files) {
               //construct the src and dest file structure
               File srcFile = new File(src, file);
               File destFile = new File(dest, file);
               //recursive copy
               copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            }

        }else{
            //if file, then copy it
            //Use bytes stream to support all file types

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 



                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                   out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
         //       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code, command you use to start your program and prints/exception you are getting.

Comment: i edited my question. it doesnt matter. I think the problem is about permissions

Comment: Add exception you are getting.

Comment: are you copying to a directory that doesn't exist?

Comment: then you need to tell us what exception did you get?

Comment: What exception ? it s work when I run it on netbeans but it not copy on jar?

Comment: the exception that is thrown when you run from jar file. if it doesn't work then it should be thown unless you consume the exception without doing anything, which is bad.

Comment: Providing [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) could help to solve your problem!

Comment: Provide the *exception.* Not a paraphrase, or a translation, or what you think it says. The fact that you don't understand it makes you the last person who should be doing any of those things.

Comment: I edit my question and I use this class. It works on run it on netbeans butit doesnt work on jar. pls help

Comment: Your code does not contain a `main()` method. Please edit your question with code that recreates your exact problem so that we can help you. In particular, we need to know how you tell this class which files to copy. Also, where are those files located in your file system?

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir") does not get the true path. /home/user/(missing desktop)/..
 why desktop is missing

Comment: Until you provide the actual exception this is not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you copying files with IO streams? Why not just do

```
File f; // bla bla init
File otherFile;
f.renameTo(otherFile);
```

Also, you need read and write permissions on the files you're trying to move (to), not on the jars you're executing ...

Comment: Cause `renameTo` move file and not copy it.

Comment: I edit my question and I use this class. It works on run it on netbeans butit doesnt work on jar. pls help.